# Javascript. Button to stop code from running

Tags: javascript, button

I am making little reaction game for fun as I am new to this, It's quite a big challenge, so, I ran into the problem, how do I make script to stop from running when the button is pressed, I've managed to start everything when the start is clicked, but can't stop it from running.
Maybe anyone have any ideas how to make this happen? Here's my code so far:

Here's my HTML:

```
        <button id="start">Start</button>

        <button id="stop">Stop</button>

        <button id="reset">Reset</button>

        <p>Your reaction time: <u><span id="timeTaken"></span></u></p>

        <p>Your average reaction time: <u><span id="average"></span></u></p>

        <p>Your best reaction time: <u><span id="best"></span></u></p>

        <div id="shape"></div>
```

And here's my javascript:

```
        var start = new Date().getTime(); 

        function getRandomColor() {     //generates random color

            var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');

            var color = '#';

            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {

                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];

            }

            return color;

        }

        function makeShapeAppear() {      //makes that shape appear on screen

            var top = Math.random() * 400;

            var left = Math.random() * 400;

            var width = (Math.random() * 200) + 100;

            if (Math.random() > 0.5) {

                document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "50%"

            } else {

                document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "0";

            }

            document.getElementById("shape").style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();

            document.getElementById("shape").style.top = top + "px";

            document.getElementById("shape").style.left = left + "px";

            document.getElementById("shape").style.width = width + "px";

            document.getElementById("shape").style.height = width + "px";

            document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "block";

            start = new Date().getTime();

        }

        function appearAfterDelay() {    //makes that shape appear after some delay

            setTimeout(makeShapeAppear, Math.random() * 3000);

        }

        document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function() {   //reset button, so when you click it, everything resets

            location.reload();

        }

        var totaltime = 0;

        var totalgames = 0;

        document.getElementById("start").onclick = function() { //start button, so when you click it, shapes start appearing and time's running

            appearAfterDelay();

            document.getElementById("shape").onclick = function() {

                document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "none";

                var end = new Date().getTime();

                var timeTaken = (end - start) / 1000;

                totaltime += timeTaken;

                totalgames += 1;

                var notroundaverage = (totaltime / totalgames);

                var roundaverage = notroundaverage.toFixed(3);

                document.getElementById("timeTaken").innerHTML = timeTaken + " s";

                document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = roundaverage + " s";

                appearAfterDelay();

            }

        }
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle of your question https://jsfiddle.net/6vvjbL0c/1/ . Does it work as expected?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. First, I'd suggest you to add some comments to your code or add a little overview of what are you doing here. Although the code is relatively small, it is not very clear why you create some shapes and what's going on, and hence what are you trying to stop. This is important because in JS you can't "stop code from running", but you can make it make some checks after which it stops. For instance, add a variable, change its value on click of the "stop" button and break some loop when the variable is changed.

Comment: @thepio Yeah, pretty much like that, but I'd like to insert stop/pause button, so when it's clicked, script stops/pauses from running and when you click start again, it continues to run, keeping your average time and so on.

Comment: @YakovL Alright, I'll try to do that!

Comment: @DovydasRamašauskas oh you want a stop button, not a reset button. My answer is not correct then but can be worked to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is event based, and you really shouldn't attempt to 'stop' it. From looking at your code I can see that what you really want to do is clear the timeout when your button is clicked. This can be achieved by placing this line:

`var timeOutId;`

at the top of your code, and changing

`setTimeout(makeShapeAppear, Math.random() * 3000);`

to

`timeOutId = setTimeout(makeShapeAppear, Math.random() * 3000);`

Then, simply add a button with a click event that clears the timeout, which can be achieved using this line: `window.clearTimeout(timeOutId);`